# Как узнать версию .NET Framework, необходимую для запуска сборки?

Tags: windows, .net

У меня есть исполнимый **EXE** файла **.NET**. Как имея только его узнать необходимую версию **.NET Framework** необходимую для запуска ?

Comment: Вам не должно этого хотеться. У приложения должен быть инсталлятор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустите ildasm из Developer Command Prompt студии (или по полному пути, у меня это C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\ildasm.exe).

Откройте в нем exe, и посмотрите MANIFEST - там будут референсы на системные сборки:

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System.Core
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

их версии совпадают с требуемой версией .NET

Answer (score 1):

Используй PowerShell

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\...\MyAssebly.dll").ImageRuntimeVersion
```

Comment: У меня лично вылетает из-за невозможности загрузить зависимости.

Answer (score 0):

Например, вы можете загрузить exe в [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases/tag/2.3.1), и посмотреть в нём. Заметьте, что сам ILSpy требует .NET 4.

Но в нормальных условиях это не должно быть нужно — приложение должно идти либо с инсталлятором, либо в его system requirements должна быть версия OS, имеющая нужную версию .NET из коробки.